# What IP address should be in the A record?

Tags: dns

When I intodns.com my site (lseafricasummit.com) it says nameserver records returned by the parent servers are:

ns1.systemdns.com   ['216.40.47.90']   [TTL=172800]

ns2.systemdns.com   ['216.40.47.90']   [TTL=172800]

ns3.systemdns.com   ['64.99.96.36']   [TTL=172800]

but the IP address on the A record right now is 64.99.64.37

Is this okay? The site really needs to be launched and the support isn't being helpful (restricting contact to email and not replying nearly quick enough). I changed the DNS 30 hours ago, and I wouldn't want that time to be wasted and have me start again and wait another 2 days. The domain is on opensrs and the reseller is from striking.ly

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the A-Record to point to your web server.  If your web server is at 64.99.64.37 then you want an A-Record for lseafricasummit.com and (typically) an A-Record for www.lseafricasummit.com to point to 64.99.64.37.

I would delete any A-Records you already have and setup those two to start.  If you need (or have) more then write those down and follow the steps below.

FYI - You don't have to wait 30+ hours for DNS to update.  The TTL for your domain is set to 48 hours.  To avoid long waits you can flush your DNS cache.  If you are using Microsoft Windows, open a command prompt and type:

> ipconfig /flushdns

then press enter.  Next type:

> ipconfig /registerdns

and press enter.  You still have to wait a bit for your authoritative DNS server to update it's records, but that shouldn't take long.  I use an AT&T DNS server and it takes 30 minutes or less.  Once the auth DNS has updated it's records you can flush your DNS to get the updated records.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will use this information to guide me with solving my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: WOW! This solved it. I was so worried and you took that away. Thanks once again, Bobby!